# Removing a character from json output

Tags: python, json, strip

This is the JSON output I will be receiving:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "@Response": "1",
        "@ErrorNumber": "0",
        "@ErrorDescription": "",
        "@ErrorDisplay": "1",
        "Transactions": [
            {
                "@Account": "xxxxxxxxxx055819",
                "@TranDate": "04/09/2020",
                "@PostDate": "04/09/2020",
                "@Description": "ValueLoad",
                "@Reference": "",
                "@Amt": "50"
            },
            {
                "@Account": "xxxxxxxxxx055819",
                "@TranDate": "04/22/2020",
                "@PostDate": "04/22/2020",
                "@Description": "Balance Adjustment Debit Cardholder",
                "@Reference": "",
                "@Amt": "-10"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

However, we need this code passed to our front end and the @ symbols will cause errors with variable conversion.

How can I strip the @ symbol from the variables below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. If your json is stored in initial_json variable, this will remove all @ symbols,

```
import re
import json


final_json = json.loads(re.sub('@', '', json.dumps(initial_json)))
```

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly how I needed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a regex to take only what you need and remove the rest.